# How to add presence check validation to an entry box in TKinter?

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Firstly, I am aware that this question has already been asked. However, none of the answers for it actually answer the question.

I am creating a program that allows details to be stored in a database. These details can also be searched for using specific data (in this case, the First Name, Surname, House number and Postcode). Therefore, in order for the details to be searched for, this data needs to be present.

I have entry boxes that allow for saving data entered to a Database, but I would like it so that it won't add the details unless the aforementioned data is entered.

In pseudocode, I would like the program to function similarly to:

```
if Firstname or Surname or House or Postcode is not present:
    output "Please enter required information"
```

Currently, this is my code for the entry boxes:

```
Label(frame1, text = "Postcode: ", font = ("arial 11"), fg = "#b83dba").grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W)
pcVar = StringVar()
pc = Entry(frame1, textvariable = pcVar, bg = "silver")
pc.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W)
```

I would preferably like it so that, when the details required are not entered, I can use the code: `messagebox.showerror("Error","Required fields are missing")`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I just found it out so I'll post how I did it in case anyone else wants to know.
If using `entryvar = Entry(frame1, textvariable = testVar)` as an example, in the code for actually saving the details you would include:

```
Q = entryvar.get() #Returns the entry's current text as a string.

if Q == "":
    messagebox.showerror("Error","Missing required fields") #Opens a messagebox informing the user that the details were not saved and that the data needs to be entered

else:
    conn.execute('''INSERT INTO TABLE (DATA)
        VALUES(?)''', (dataNew);
    conn.commit()

    messagebox.showinfo("Success","Details Saved") #Opens a messagebox informing the user that the details have saved
```

Apologies for my SQL as I am not very confident in that language.